# How to get data from POST method using browser developer tools

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am attempting to do web scraping in this [site](https://www.bullmarketbrokers.com/). As in similar sites that require user log in, the first step is submitting username and password in order to get a cookie from where the scraping would begin.

Most documentation on the web suggest using developer tools in browser to find the POST method (that contains the information for username and password), and use a library (i.e. request) to "mimic" the login process in Python

However, I cannot find a POST method in browser developer tools for this site. Any ideas on how to overcome this limitation?

Comment: You have not linked "a web site that does not use POST method" for login. When observing my own browser's developer tools, I notice a `POST` immediately upon selecting the login button.

Comment: @esqew In my developer tools that post method appears for just a moment (I can see it for a fraction of a second) and then disappears. After the browser finishes loading all the content, I look at the list under ‘network’ and cannot find the POST method. Perhaps I should change the title to “POST method disappears from developer tools”

Comment: It may be helpful for you (as well as future visitors to this question) to re-phrase your question to be an inquiry as to how to use the developer tools in your browser to get more information about the `POST` request itself, rather than insinuating that a `POST` doesn't occur at all.

Comment: @esqew Agree. Question re-phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @esqew, there actually is a POST method, only that I couldn't see it in my developer tools as it showed for a very little time and didn't persist. I fixed that by enabling "Preserve log" checkbox under "Network" (I'm using Google Chrome)